# RuntimeError: Expected object of scalar type Long but got scalar type Float for argument #2 'mat2' how to fix it?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, typing

```
import torch.nn as nn 
import torch 
import torch.optim as optim
import itertools

class net1(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(net1,self).__init__()

        self.pipe = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(10,10),
            nn.ReLU()
        )

    def forward(self,x):
        return self.pipe(x.long())

class net2(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(net2,self).__init__()

        self.pipe = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(10,20),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(20,10)
        )

    def forward(self,x):
        return self.pipe(x.long())



netFIRST = net1()
netSECOND = net2()

learning_rate = 0.001

opt = optim.Adam(itertools.chain(netFIRST.parameters(),netSECOND.parameters()), lr=learning_rate)

epochs = 1000

x = torch.tensor([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],dtype=torch.long)
y = torch.tensor([10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1],dtype=torch.long)


for epoch in range(epochs):
    opt.zero_grad()

    prediction = netSECOND(netFIRST(x))
    loss = (y.long() - prediction)**2
    loss.backward()

    print(loss)
    print(prediction)
    opt.step()
```

error:

> line 49, in  prediction = netSECOND(netFIRST(x))
>
> line 1371, in linear; output = input.matmul(weight.t())
>
> RuntimeError: Expected object of scalar type Long but got scalar type
>   Float for argument #2 'mat2'

I don't really see what I'm doing wrong. I have tried to turn everything in a `Long` in every possible way. I don't really get the way typing works for pytorch. Last time I tried something with just one layer and it forced me to use type `int`.
Could someone explain how the typing is established in pytorch and how to prevent and fix errors like this??
A lot I mean an awful lot of thanks in advance, this problem really bothers me and I can't seem to fix it no matter what I try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The weights are Floats, the inputs are Longs. This is not allowed. In fact, I don't think torch supports anything else than Floats in neural networks.

If you remove *all* calls to long, and define your input as floats, it will work (it does, I tried).

(You will then get another unrelated error: you need to sum your loss)

Comment: Never mind figured out how it worked. I needed to remove all the dtype long and then change the dtype to torch.float and the summation in the loss ofcourse.

Comment: you're very welcome. Please mark the answer as accepted (click on the tick mark) if it was satisfactory.